# build a treeview with a directive recursive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

i begin in angular jsand i want build a treeview with a directive recursive in angularjs.
for this, i based on this exemple :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKPpv/3/)

and see me code :

the template :

```
<aside id="left-panel">
    <nav>
        <treeview></treeview>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

and the two directives :

treeview

```
angular.module('app').directive('treeview', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="sl-treeview">' +
                    '<ul ng-transclude>' +
                        '<treeview-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></treeview-item>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                  '</div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            console.log('treeview directive loaded');
        },
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope)
        {
            $rootScope.depth = 0;
            $scope.items = $rootScope.modules.submodules;
        }
    };
});
```

and see the $scope.items values :

```
[{
   id: 2,
   name: 'Modules',
   moduleStandardId: 2,
   applicationId: 1,
   picto: 'fa fa-cubes',
   color: '#68DB62',
   functions: [],
   submodules: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Module',
        moduleStandardId: 2,
        applicationId: 1,
        picto: 'fa fa-cube',
        color: '#60C8E5',
        functions: [
          {
             id: 1,
             name: 'CreateModule',
             title: 'CreateModule',
             description: 'Créer un module',
             moduleId: 3
          }
   ],
   submodules: []
},
{
   id: 4,
   name: 'Fonction',
   moduleStandardId: 2,
   applicationId: 1,
   picto: 'fa fa-gears',
   color: '#F20E0E',
   functions: [
      {
         id: 1,
         name: 'CreateFunction',
         title: 'CreateFunction',
         description: 'Créer une fonction pour un module',
         moduleId: 4
      }
   ],
   submodules: []
}]
```

and treeview-item :

```
angular.module('app').directive('treeviewItem', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<li><a href="">{{item.name}}</a></li>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            console.log('item');
            scope.$watch('item.submodules', function()
            {
                element.append(
                  $compile(
                    '<ul>' +
                        '<treeview-item ng-repeat="childitem in item.submodules" item="childitem"></treeview-item>' +
                    '</ul>'
                  )(scope)
                );
            });
            console.log('treeview item directive loaded');
        }
    };
});
```

and in result, i get that :

```
<div class="sl-treeview ng-isolate-scope">
    <ul ng-transclude=""></ul>
</div>
```

i tested differents things :

- if i pass in the directives : yes (with the console.log)
- if the watch work : yes i put a console.log('lalalala') and i have 'lalalala' 3 times
- the element in treeview-item seems good,
- the items aren't null

i don't understand why the $compile don't work... 
thanks in advance for the help :)

Finally i think it's my ng-transclude which don't work